# build Kaa node RPM package fail

Tags: rpmbuild, kaa

I am trying to build Kaa-node Debian/RPM packages.
The Debian package had built successfully.
But, the RPM package build fail on Ubuntu and CentOS platform.

I use follow command to build package:
mvn -DskipTests -P compile-gwt,mongo-dao,mariadb-dao,cassandra,couchbase,kafka,oracle-nosql,build-rpm clean install verify

On CentOS, it show below error message:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:attached-rpm (default) on project kaa-node: Unable to build the RPM: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "rpmbuild" (in directory "/root/kaa-0.9/kaa/server/node/target/rpm/kaa-node/SPECS"): error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

On Ubuntu, it show below error message:
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.1.3:attached-rpm (default) on project kaa-node: Unable to query for default vendor from RPM: Error while executing process. Cannot run program "rpm": error=2, No such file or directory -> [Help 1]

Have anyone can give suggestion about this question, thanks.

Comment: Which branch did you build on?

Comment: I follow the [on-line document](http://docs.kaaproject.org/display/KAA/Building+Kaa+server+from+source) and use "git clone https://github.com/kaaproject/kaa.git" command to get the source.

Comment: I also try to download the code from "release-0.9" branch on the github website. But, it still build fail with the same error message

Comment: Did you check rpm exists in your environment? If not -- try to run `apt-get install rpm`  or through `yum` on CentOS.

Comment: Yes, it seems I miss to install rpm. The rpm package can be built successfully, now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Install rpm package on your OS.

Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install rpm
```

CentOS:

```
$ sudo yum install rpm-build
```